# Strange Syntax Error MySQL Error when using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

I've got an syntax error near line 1 somewhere in this code:

```
//...
$nr = 126;
$expl = "'test'";
$da = "'2003-12-01'";
$tax = 2.5;
$cost = 100;

//Here is the error
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl (type, nr, explan, date, tax, cost) VALUES('Example'," + $nr + ",'"+ $expl + "','" + $da + "'," + $tax + "," + $cost + ");";
```

This is the error log:

```
Error: 103.5
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '103.5' at line 1
```

I'm using PHP version is 5.6.3 and MySQL version 5.6.21

I cant figure out, what the problem is :(

Comment: `JS` !== `PHP`, so simple. JS concatenation operator: `+`; PHP `.` <-- Not the same character! (After this you have a few quotes messed up and you can remove the semicolon at the end)

Comment: How many *OMG's* am I allowed here, without going over-quota?

Comment: @Fred-ii- just 4. Keep it under 4...

Comment: *OMG-OMG-OMG-OMG*  - thanks @Mike I wouldn't want to break the Stack *OMG* bank.

Comment: @Fred-ii- OMG DUDE! I said **UNDER** 4.

Comment: @Mike *Darn it*. I'll blame it on the mouse. Sneaky as it is. No cheese for them tonight. Ok, it's a myth that mice eat cheese, but nonetheless; it makes for some great advertising props.

Comment: Heyyyyy hold on here => ***just 4**. Keep it under 4* the first one counted just like the first answer in Family Feud @Mike but I'll keep it "under 4" next time, just to be safe ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- By golly, you're right. I should have been more clear. Anyway I use chunky peanut butter in my mouse traps. They looove peanut butter. Good huntin'!

Comment: @Mike Yep, that they do! Plus, muffins and those crazy little nut looking things. Ouuhh, they just love that, laced with that special ingredient; oh yummy. (*Qualified hunter*) ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `+` to concatenate strings, that doesn't work in PHP. You have to use `.`.

There is probably some strange arithmatic going on that produces `103.5`, like `2.5 + "," + 100`. Where `","` is converted to `int(1)` or something.